# Can't import System.Web namespace

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, system.web

I am trying to use:

```
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
```

In windows forms, but it tells me a reference is missing. So I went in the add reference but System.Web isn't on the list. I even tried going to the physical location of System.Web.Dll but when I added it it told me that it can't find the assembly.

I have no problem importing the assembly in an ASP.NET application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [System.Web.Hosting not found in VS2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376626/system-web-hosting-not-found-in-vs2008)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note if your project targets ".NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile" then this class will not work, you need to re-target your project to ".NET Framework 4.0" instead.  [Credit to Matt Neerincx [MSFT] who posted this on msdn]

Comment: I am quite confident this guy is right. This has bitten me more than once. Why can't I set my framework version to the full 4.0 framework by default?!

Comment: Yes, this is what it turned out to be in the end. What a useless feature!!